# Blackberry Bold CSS

Tags: css, blackberry, mobile, rim-4.6

I was reviewing the CSS docs for version 4.6 and saw this in the doc:
"In BlackBerry Device Software version 4.6, the BlackBerry Browser provides full support for CSS 2.1, excluding pseudo-elements and dynamic pseudo-classes, system fonts, and generated content."

I am running the 4.6.0.190 emulator for the bold and I cannot get any padding to work.  My other CSS is working fine, such as font family and font size but that is about it.  Anything related to the box model (margins, padding) and positioning does not work and according to the docs, it should.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing I've noticed doing development on the BlackBerry emulator is that it is very inaccurate in a lot of situations compared to the actual device.

Unfortunately I don't have a list of what things work or don't work the same as the physical device on the emulator, however I've noticed several small discrepancies that make it (in my opinion) almost useless to rely upon for development.

Many of these discrepancies are box model related. For example, the padding on the real BlackBerry Bold behaves properly, while the emulator gives more padding than it should, causing things to render wrong.

Box model related things do work on the emulators I've tried, however I've had some problems, especially related to widths of elements, however not the same issues you've described.

My recommendation is to get your hands on a BlackBerry Bold to really see what everything looks like.